# SharePoint CSOM in .NET Core Azure function running on Linux

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, sharepoint-online, csom

Looking for advice, not necessarily any actual code.  I'm a consultant writing some de-duplication functionality into an existing SharePoint Online \ Azure functions solution for a client.

**The requirement:** I need to write an Azure function that pulls PDF's from a SharePoint library, so I can hash check it before running it through OCR (ComputerVision API), followed by some text processing and a final similarity check.

**The challenge:** The client environment is locked down to the n-th degree (financial institution) and I only have access to the Azure resource group I'm currently working in. The existing function app, used by other solutions, runs on runtime 2.0 and Linux. I need to use SharePoint CSOM to access the PDF's for the above mentioned checks, but runtime 2.0 only supports .NET Core (not .NET framework), and .NET Core doesn't support SharePoint CSOM. There is a workaround to get CSOM working in .NET Core by fiddling with target build settings, but then it still doesn't run on Linux. Logic Apps doesn't give me the granularity to run all the checks and balances I need to, and SPFX isn't really a solution to do nightly automated runs without some garish compromises. VM's are out.

Any thoughts or suggestions to get this up and running without shooting myself or my client in the foot?

Comment: I feel like if the file is on SPO you should be able to get to from the Graph if it is a group connected site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two options:

- Using the raw REST APIs with .Net Core running in Linux. You'll need to figure out how to generate the auth token. I know it can be done but don't have sample code for you at this time.
- If Node is an option for you, you can use PnP JS in a Node Azure function. https://spblog.net/post/2017/06/07/Using-PnP-JS-Core-(sp-pnp-js)-in-Nodejs-environment

Do not even bother trying to get the CSOM to work. Also I don't even see how SPFX will work in this case.

Comment: Node might be an option, it seems.  You’re a lifesaver, Derek, thank you